# Swagger With Static Documentation

Tags: rest, documentation-generation, swagger

I am looking to use Swagger to document my restful interface. The problem is that I do not want to automatically generate my documentation by annotating my code. Basically I don't want to couple my internal data model to the virtual data model exposed by the interface. It appears that I can just have my server provide a Resources.json file and then a corresponding JSON file for each resource handler. However, when I tried this I ran into lots of little gotchas while attempting to define the JSON correct syntax and provide the correct HTTP header response fields.

Has anyone used Swagger in this way? Anyone have some documentation or examples? Everything that I could find centered around simply using the client libraries to generate things for you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've created static json files for swagger before.  The documentation is kinda lacking in describing the json required to get swagger to work.

If you look at their [spec](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec) and look at their example [petstore.json](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore.json). You should be able to get a pretty good idea of how to structure your json.

Or look at my examples.

If you have any more questions feel free to ask.

main.json

```
{
    "apiVersion": "0.0.4542.22887",
    "swaggerVersion": "1.0",
    "basePath": "http://local.api.com/api/doc",
    "apis": [
        {
            "path": "/donuts",
            "description": "Operations about donuts"
        },
        {
            "path": "/cakes",
            "description": "Operations about cakes"
        },
        {
            "path": "/bagels",
            "description": "Operations about bagels"
        }
    ]

}
```

donuts.json

```
{
    "apiVersion": "0.0.4542.22887",
    "swaggerVersion": "1.0",
    "basePath": "http://local.api.com/api",
    "resourcePath": "/donuts",
    "apis": [
        {
            "path": "/donuts/{page}/{pagesize}",
            "description": "Get donuts by page",
            "operations": [
                {
                    "httpMethod": "GET",
                    "notes": "Get a donut with page and size",
                    "nickname": "getDonutsByPageAndSize",
                    "summary": "Get a collection of donuts by page and pagesize.",
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "page",
                            "description": "the page of the collection",
                            "dataType": "int",
                            "required": true,
                            "allowMultiple": false,
                            "paramType": "path"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "pagesize",
                            "description": "the size of the collection",
                            "dataType": "int",
                            "required": true,
                            "allowMultiple": false,
                            "paramType": "path"
                        }
                    ],
                    "errorResponses": [ ]
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple examples. That is really helpful. Could you also provide what HTTP requests my server needs to respond to in order properly support the sandbox JavaScript client?

Comment: http://local.api.com/api/doc will respond with main.json
http://local.api.com/api/doc/donuts will response with donuts.json

Keep in mind that main.json points to path '/donuts'.  Swagger will take the base path from main.json (http:.../api/doc) and append the api specific endpoint for donut (/donuts)

Comment: Broken links. Also, do you have any examples of including authentication in the spec?

Comment: For much improved spec of the format see new repo and spec: https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/1.2.md

Answer (score 2):

I have created json from PHP files using swagger PHP here is my code if anyone is looking for, hope it helps

```
<?php
namespace carParking\Resources;

use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;

/**
 * @package
 * @category
 * @subpackage
 *
 * @SWG\Resource(
 *   apiVersion="1.0.0",
 *   swaggerVersion="1.2",
 *   basePath="http://192.168.3.42/swagger/api",
 *   resourcePath="/car",
 *   description="Car Parking System",
 *   produces="['application/json','application/xml','text/plain','text/html']"
 * )
 */
class Car
{
/**
 * @SWG\Api(
 *   path="/car/car.php?carId={carId}",
 *   @SWG\Operation(
 *     method="GET",
 *     summary="Find car by ID",
 *     notes="Returns a car based on ID",
 *     type="Car",
 *     nickname= "getCarById",
 *     authorizations={},
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *       name="carId",
 *       description="ID of car that needs to be fetched",
 *       required=true,
 *       type="integer",
 *       format="int64",
 *       paramType="path",
 *       allowMultiple=false
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=400, message="Invalid ID supplied"),
 *     @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=404, message="car not found")
 *   )
 * )
 */
public function getCarById() {
    echo "getCarById";
}

/**
 * @SWG\Api(
 *   path="/car/fetchAll.php",
 *   @SWG\Operation(
 *     method="GET",
 *     summary="Fetch all parked cars",
 *     notes="Returns all cars parked",
 *     type="Car",
 *     nickname= "getAllParkedCars",
 *     authorizations={},
 *     @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=404, message="car not found")
 *   )
 * )
 */
public function getAllParkedCars() {
    echo "getAllParkedCars";
}

/**
 * @SWG\Api(
 *   path="/car/delete.php",
 *   @SWG\Operation(
 *     method="DELETE",
 *     summary="Deletes a Car",
 *     notes="Delete a parked car",
 *     type="void",
 *     nickname= "deleteCar",
 *     @SWG\Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
 *     authorizations={},
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *       name="carId",
 *       description="ID of car that needs to be deleted",
 *       required=true,
 *       type="integer",
 *       format="int64",
 *       paramType="form",
 *       allowMultiple=false
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=400, message="Invalid ID supplied"),
 *     @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=404, message="car not found")
 *   )
 * )
 */
public function deleteCar() {
    echo "deleteCar";
}

/**
 * @SWG\Api(
 *   path="/car/add.php",
 *   @SWG\Operation(
 *     method="POST",
 *     summary="Add Car",
 *     notes="Add car to parking",
 *     type="array",
 *     @SWG\Items("car"),
 *     nickname= "addCar",
 *     authorizations={},
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *       name="parking_section_id",
 *       description="Parking Area ID",
 *       required=true,
 *       type="integer",
 *       format="int64",
 *       paramType="form",
 *       allowMultiple=false
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *       name="car_number",
 *       description="Car Number",
 *       required=true,
 *       type="integer",
 *       format="int64",
 *       paramType="form",
 *       allowMultiple=false
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *       name="cost",
 *       description="Cost of Parking",
 *       required=true,
 *       type="integer",
 *       format="int64",
 *       paramType="form",
 *       allowMultiple=false
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=400, message="Invalid ID supplied"),
 *     @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=404, message="car not found")
 *   )
 * )
 */
public function addCar() {
    echo "addCar";
}

/**
 * @SWG\Api(
 *   path="/car/getCost.php",
 *   @SWG\Operation(
 *     method="POST",
 *     summary="Parking Cost of the Car Parked",
 *     notes="Parking Cost of the Car Parked",
 *     type="void",
 *     nickname= "getCost",
 *     authorizations={},
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *       name="carId",
 *       description="Parking Area ID",
 *       required=true,
 *       type="integer",
 *       format="int64",
 *       paramType="form",
 *       allowMultiple=false
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=405, message="Invalid input")
 *   )
 * )
 */
public function getCost() {
    echo "getCost";
}

/**
 * @SWG\Api(
 *   path="/car/deleteAll.php",
 *   @SWG\Operation(
 *     method="DELETE",
 *     summary="Delete all car parking",
 *     notes="Delete all car parking",
 *     type="void",
 *     nickname= "deleteAll",
 *     @SWG\Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
 *     authorizations={}
 *   )
 * )
 */
public function deleteAll() {
    echo "deleteAll";
}

/**
 * @SWG\Api(
 *   path="/car/testPut.php",
 *   @SWG\Operation(
 *     method="PUT",
 *     summary="Testing Put",
 *     notes="Testing Put",
 *     type="void",
 *     nickname= "testWithFormPut",
 *     @SWG\Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
 *     authorizations={},
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *       name="firstPara",
 *       description="First Parameter",
 *       required=true,
 *       type="integer",
 *       format="int64",
 *       paramType="form",
 *       allowMultiple=false
 *     ),
  *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *       name="secondPara",
 *       description="Second Parameter",
 *       required=true,
 *       type="integer",
 *       format="int64",
 *       paramType="form",
 *       allowMultiple=false
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=405, message="Invalid input")
 *   )
 * )
 */
public function testWithFormPut() {
    echo "testWithFormPut";
}

/**
 * @SWG\Api(
 *   path="/car/testPatch.php",
 *   @SWG\Operation(
 *     method="PATCH",
 *     summary="Testing Patch",
 *     notes="Testing Patch",
 *     type="void",
 *     nickname= "testWithFormPatch",
 *     @SWG\Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
 *     authorizations={},
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *       name="firstPara",
 *       description="First Parameter",
 *       required=true,
 *       type="integer",
 *       format="int64",
 *       paramType="form",
 *       allowMultiple=false
 *     ),
  *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *       name="secondPara",
 *       description="Second Parameter",
 *       required=true,
 *       type="integer",
 *       format="int64",
 *       paramType="form",
 *       allowMultiple=false
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=405, message="Invalid input")
 *   )
 * )
 */
public function testWithFormPatch() {
    echo "testWithFormPatch";
}

/**
 * @SWG\Api(
 *   path="/car/carJsonTest.php",
 *   @SWG\Operation(
 *     method="POST",
 *     summary="Send and parse JSON",
 *     notes="Send and parse JSON",
 *     type="void",
 *     authorizations={},
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *       name="body",
 *       description="Sample JSON need to be passed",
 *       required=true,
 *       type="Car",
 *       paramType="body",
 *       allowMultiple=false
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=405, message="Invalid input")
 *   )
 * )
 */
public function carJsonTest() {
    echo "carJsonTest";
}
```

Model code:

```
<?php
namespace carStore\Models;

use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;

/**
 * @package
 * @category
 * @subpackage
 *
 * @SWG\Model(id="Car",required="parking_section_id, car_number, cost")
 */
class Car
{
/**
 *         @SWG\Property(name="parking_section_id",type="integer",format="int64",minimum="0.0",maximum="100.0",description="unique identifier for the parking")
 */
public $parking_section_id;

 /**
 * @SWG\Property(name="car_number",type="integer",format="int64",description="unique identifier for the car")
 */
public $car_number;


 /**
 * @SWG\Property(name="cost",type="integer",format="int64",description="cost for the parking")
 */
public $cost;



 }
```

}

here us JSON code for swagger UI:

```
 {
"basePath": "http://192.168.3.42/swagger/api",
"swaggerVersion": "1.2",
"apiVersion": "1.0.0",
"resourcePath": "/car",
"apis": [
    {
        "path": "/car/add.php",
        "operations": [
            {
                "method": "POST",
                "summary": "Add Car",
                "nickname": "addCar",
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "$ref": "car"
                },
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "paramType": "form",
                        "name": "parking_section_id",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "required": true,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "description": "Parking Area ID",
                        "format": "int64"
                    },
                    {
                        "paramType": "form",
                        "name": "car_number",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "required": true,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "description": "Car Number",
                        "format": "int64"
                    },
                    {
                        "paramType": "form",
                        "name": "cost",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "required": true,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "description": "Cost of Parking",
                        "format": "int64"
                    }
                ],
                "responseMessages": [
                    {
                        "code": 400,
                        "message": "Invalid ID supplied"
                    },
                    {
                        "code": 404,
                        "message": "car not found"
                    }
                ],
                "notes": "Add car to parking",
                "authorizations": {

                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "path": "/car/car.php?carId={carId}",
        "operations": [
            {
                "method": "GET",
                "summary": "Find car by ID",
                "nickname": "getCarById",
                "type": "Car",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "paramType": "path",
                        "name": "carId",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "required": true,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "description": "ID of car that needs to be fetched",
                        "format": "int64"
                    }
                ],
                "responseMessages": [
                    {
                        "code": 400,
                        "message": "Invalid ID supplied"
                    },
                    {
                        "code": 404,
                        "message": "car not found"
                    }
                ],
                "notes": "Returns a car based on ID",
                "authorizations": {

                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "path": "/car/carJsonTest.php",
        "operations": [
            {
                "method": "POST",
                "summary": "Send and parse JSON",
                "nickname": "carJsonTest",
                "type": "void",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "paramType": "body",
                        "name": "body",
                        "type": "Car",
                        "required": true,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "description": "Sample JSON need to be passed"
                    }
                ],
                "responseMessages": [
                    {
                        "code": 405,
                        "message": "Invalid input"
                    }
                ],
                "notes": "Send and parse JSON",
                "authorizations": {

                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "path": "/car/delete.php",
        "operations": [
            {
                "method": "DELETE",
                "summary": "Deletes a Car",
                "nickname": "deleteCar",
                "type": "void",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "paramType": "form",
                        "name": "carId",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "required": true,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "description": "ID of car that needs to be deleted",
                        "format": "int64"
                    }
                ],
                "responseMessages": [
                    {
                        "code": 400,
                        "message": "Invalid ID supplied"
                    },
                    {
                        "code": 404,
                        "message": "car not found"
                    }
                ],
                "notes": "Delete a parked car",
                "consumes": [
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                ],
                "authorizations": {

                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "path": "/car/deleteAll.php",
        "operations": [
            {
                "method": "DELETE",
                "summary": "Delete all car parking",
                "nickname": "deleteAll",
                "type": "void",
                "notes": "Delete all car parking",
                "consumes": [
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                ],
                "authorizations": {

                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "path": "/car/fetchAll.php",
        "operations": [
            {
                "method": "GET",
                "summary": "Fetch all parked cars",
                "nickname": "getAllParkedCars",
                "type": "Car",
                "responseMessages": [
                    {
                        "code": 404,
                        "message": "car not found"
                    }
                ],
                "notes": "Returns all cars parked",
                "authorizations": {

                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "path": "/car/getCost.php",
        "operations": [
            {
                "method": "POST",
                "summary": "Parking Cost of the Car Parked",
                "nickname": "getCost",
                "type": "void",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "paramType": "form",
                        "name": "carId",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "required": true,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "description": "Parking Area ID",
                        "format": "int64"
                    }
                ],
                "responseMessages": [
                    {
                        "code": 405,
                        "message": "Invalid input"
                    }
                ],
                "notes": "Parking Cost of the Car Parked",
                "authorizations": {

                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "path": "/car/testPatch.php",
        "operations": [
            {
                "method": "PATCH",
                "summary": "Testing Patch",
                "nickname": "testWithFormPatch",
                "type": "void",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "paramType": "form",
                        "name": "firstPara",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "required": true,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "description": "First Parameter",
                        "format": "int64"
                    },
                    {
                        "paramType": "form",
                        "name": "secondPara",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "required": true,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "description": "Second Parameter",
                        "format": "int64"
                    }
                ],
                "responseMessages": [
                    {
                        "code": 405,
                        "message": "Invalid input"
                    }
                ],
                "notes": "Testing Patch",
                "consumes": [
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                ],
                "authorizations": {

                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "path": "/car/testPut.php",
        "operations": [
            {
                "method": "PUT",
                "summary": "Testing Put",
                "nickname": "testWithFormPut",
                "type": "void",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "paramType": "form",
                        "name": "firstPara",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "required": true,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "description": "First Parameter",
                        "format": "int64"
                    },
                    {
                        "paramType": "form",
                        "name": "secondPara",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "required": true,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "description": "Second Parameter",
                        "format": "int64"
                    }
                ],
                "responseMessages": [
                    {
                        "code": 405,
                        "message": "Invalid input"
                    }
                ],
                "notes": "Testing Put",
                "consumes": [
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                ],
                "authorizations": {

                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"models": {
    "Car": {
        "id": "Car",
        "required": [
            "car_number",
            "cost",
            "parking_section_id"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "parking_section_id": {
                "description": "unique identifier for the parking",
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int64",
                "minimum": "0.0",
                "maximum": "100.0"
            },
            "car_number": {
                "description": "unique identifier for the car",
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int64"
            },
            "cost": {
                "description": "cost for the parking",
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int64"
            }
        }
    }
},
"produces": [
    "application/json",
    "application/xml",
    "text/plain",
    "text/html"
]
}
```

Give the json path in api-doc.json

Comment: if anyone need any more help feel free to ask :)

Comment: Hi Syed, please let me know, if you can help me out with this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252510/web-api-documentation-using-swagger