# Swagger UI error: Unable to fetch API Listing

Tags: swagger

I'm documenting a REST web API with [Swagger](http://swagger.wordnik.com/). I've downloaded the petstore example. It consists of the `resources.json` which references `pet.json` and `user.json`:

```
{
    "apiVersion":"0.2",
    "swaggerVersion":"1.0",
    "basePath":"http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api",
    "apis":
    [
        {
            "path":"/pet.{format}",
            "description":"Operations about pets"
        },
        {
            "path":"/user.{format}",
            "description":"Operations about user"
        }
    ]
}
```

But even after uploading the original files to my web server, Swagger UI tells me:

```
Unable to fetch API Listing. Tried the following urls:
http://www.myserver.org/resources.json
http://www.myserver.org
http://www.myserver.org/resources.json
http://www.myserver.org/resources
```

Can you tell what causes Swagger not find my json file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're going to www.myserver.org and it brings up the swagger ui?  In the "Explore" textbox in the Swagger UI... be sure to type in the location of your resources.json.

I personally have my swagger api documentation set up this way...

```
http://adamclerk.com/api            --Swagger UI
http://adamclerk.com/api/doc        --returns json representing resources.js
http://adamclerk.com/api/doc/donuts --returns json representing donut operations
```

you can checkout a more detailed explaination here - [Swagger With Static Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560857/swagger-with-static-documentation/10969894#10969894)

If you have any more questions feel free to ask.